# When trying to edit JNLP file, it is saying file is open in another program, so cannot edit

Tags: java, windows, edit, jnlp

I have a JNLP file as part of a project kept in webapps folder in Red5 server in Windows 8. I deployed the server, and then tried to access the JNLP file in Internet Explorer. A Java popup came, and it said, Launch failed due to application error. I closed the Java popup. I stopped the server. I then opened the JNLP file in the text editor to make necessary changes.

But, now when I am trying to save the file, it is saying `"Please check whether if this file is opened in another program"`.

My server is shut down, IE is closed. I checked in Task Manager and there is no javaw.exe is running. I even restarted the computer. Still I am unable to save this file due to the same error!

Does this mean the JNLP file is still running somewhere? How can I find that app and kill it?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Open Task Manager using `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`,switch to Process tab and kill any process associated with that JNLP file!

Comment: I tried that already. But, I don't know how to identify which process is associated with the JNLP file.

Comment: Try killing all your server related process including server. If this doesn't help,save your updated text to a new temp file and close and restart your editor program!

Comment: None of the server related process is running. I have even restarted the computer. So, text editor was closed, and the file was not open anywhere. After machine restart, when I edited the file in text editor, it again said, file is being used.

Comment: Probably the root causes appear to be `temp`,`%temp%` folder. Please remove the contents of these folder by searching them using `Run` option on Windows!

Comment: Deleted everything from the temp folder. Still no luck :(